# $f(x) \text{ irreducible in } R[x] \iff f(ax+b) \text{ irreducible in } R[x] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $a\in U(R)$ an invertible element of $R$ and $b\in R $. I will prove that the following are equivalent:

- $f(x)$ is irreducible  in $R[x]$.
- $f(ax+b)$ is irreducible in $R[x]$.

First of all $f(x)$ and $ f(ax+b)$ have always the same degree $n$.

We suppose that $f(x)$ is irreducible. If $f(ax+b)$ is not irreducible, then there exists some $g(x),h(x)\in R[x]$ with $0<\deg g(x),\deg h(x)<n$ such that
$$f(ax+b)=g(x)h(x)$$ and if we put $a^{-1}x-b$ instead of $x$ we take $f(x)=g(ax-b)h(ax-b)$ with $0<\deg g(ax-b),\deg h(ax-b)<n$ and that means that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $R[x]$. Contradiction.

We work similar for the converse.

Is this right?

Comment: Here's half an idea. Show that the mapping $x \mapsto ax+b$ is an automorphism. The claim is that automorphisms respect irreducibility. Suppose to the contrary they did not, and derive some contradiction, perhaps that something which is known to be irreducible is perhaps reducible.

Comment: $f(x)=g(x)h(x)\iff f(ax+b)=g(ax+b)h(ax+b)$

Comment: Any other ideas? Is my first step completely right?

Comment: It's correct, except you prove the equivalence by contrapositive really, not by contradiction: $f(x)$ is not irreducible iff $f(ax+b)$ is not irreducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Proposition**
Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $U(R)$ be its group of invertible elements. Let $f\in R[x]$, $a\in U(R)$, $b\in R$, and set $g(x)=f(a x+b)$. Then $f$ is irreducible iff $g$ is.

**Proof**
Suppose $f=st$ is reducible with non-constant $s,t\in R[x]$, so that $f(a x+b)=s(a x+b)t(a x+b)$. Then put $u(x)=s(a x+b)$, and $v(x)=t(a x+b)$, for some non-constant $u,v\in R[x]$, we then have $g(x)=u(x)v(x)$, so $g$ is reducible. The converse is by symmetry, since $g(a^{-1} x-a^{-1}b)=f(a (a^{-1} x-a^{-1}b)+b)=f(x)$.